# How to recode all values to lowercase but ignore TRUE and FALSE?

Tags: r, lowercase, recode

I have data that I want to convert to lowercase and separate with underscores using `snakecase::to_any_case()`. However, I wish to ignore cells that contain either `TRUE`/`FALSE` and keep them as uppercase.

#### Data

*for making a reproducible example*

```r
library(dplyr)

df <-
  tibble(animals = c("Peregrine falcon", "Golden eagle", TRUE, "White-throated needletail swift"),
           cars = c("Hennessey Venom GT", FALSE, "Bugatti Chiron Super Sport 300+", "Hennessey Venom F5"),
           airplanes = c("North American X-15", "Lockheed SR-71 Blackbird", FALSE, "Lockheed YF-12")) %>%
  mutate_all(as.character)

##   animals                         cars                            airplanes               
##   <chr>                           <chr>                           <chr>                   
## 1 Peregrine falcon                Hennessey Venom GT              North American X-15     
## 2 Golden eagle                    FALSE                           Lockheed SR-71 Blackbird
## 3 TRUE                            Bugatti Chiron Super Sport 300+ FALSE                   
## 4 White-throated needletail swift Hennessey Venom F5              Lockheed YF-12
```

#### Recoding data

```r
library(snakecase)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), to_any_case))      # dplyr 1.0.2

##   animals                         cars                           airplanes               
##   <chr>                           <chr>                          <chr>                   
## 1 peregrine_falcon                hennessey_venom_gt             north_american_x_15     
## 2 golden_eagle                    false                          lockheed_sr_71_blackbird
## 3 true                            bugatti_chiron_super_sport_300 false                   
## 4 white_throated_needletail_swift hennessey_venom_f_5            lockheed_yf_12
```

#### But I'm trying to achieve this

```r
  animals                         cars                           airplanes               
  <chr>                           <chr>                          <chr>                   
1 peregrine_falcon                hennessey_venom_gt             north_american_x_15     
2 golden_eagle                    FALSE                          lockheed_sr_71_blackbird
3 TRUE                            bugatti_chiron_super_sport_300 FALSE                   
4 white_throated_needletail_swift hennessey_venom_f_5            lockheed_yf_12
```

How can I run `mutate(across(everything(), to_any_case))` while ignoring `TRUE` and `FALSE` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in `dplyr` syntax, but the following should work:

```r
library(snakecase)

to_any_no_tf <- function(x) {
    ifelse(!grepl("^(?:TRUE|FALSE)$", x), to_any_case(x), x)
}

df %>% mutate(across(everything(), to_any_no_tf))
```

The logic here is to use `grepl` to check if the input value be the strings `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  If so, then we do not apply any case logic to them, otherwise we call `to_any_case()` as you are already doing.